# Question about indutive loads in power system

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, power

Our home appliances are mostly resistive loads and the bill we pay for consuming power is actually real power. If we use more inductive loads at our home, will it just cause problems in power factor or does it affect our bill as well (in the form of consuming more units despite it consume reactive power)?

Comment: in short inductive loads increase our bill ?does it consume more units than resitive load?does consuming more reactive power have anything to do with our electric billing system?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electricity bills rather than physics.

Comment: I think it is about physics because it's about the [phase angle/power factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor) of electrical devices.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Electrical systems and circuitry. As such it would find a better home on ElectricalEngineering.SE

Answer (score 1):

yes, you will have to pay more if your load is inductive. most of energy meters work with the voltage and current to calculate energy. When we have inductive load it takes more current than resistive load to produce same power or output.
   P=V.I.Cosx   where x is the phase angle between voltage(V) and current(I).
if the phase angle x goes higher, the power or output will decrese and the current will increse to produce the same output at constant voltage, therefore your electricity bill will also go up due to the working principle of energy meter.

Answer (score 0):

A load is only purely inductive as long as you aren't taking any energy out of it. So a purely inductive load would certainly give us a low (zero!) electricity bill, but it wouldn't be much use as a domestic appliance since it couldn't do anything. Once your appliance starts doing any work it is no longer a purely inductive load.

If an appliance does work, or in the case of a heater generates heat, that energy has to come from somewhere and obviously it comes from the electricity supplier who will charge you for the privilege. There isn't any way round this. Redesigning your appliance to present a different type of load can't create energy from nowhere.